# git update-index --assume-unchanged discrepancy in egit

Tags: git, egit

Here's the scenario:

I have a git project open in eclipse + egit (the git plugin) with a resource file called samples.xml.

I would like to remove samples.xml, but tell git to ignore the change. So I do the following:

```
rm samples.xml
git update-index --assume-unchanged samples.xml
```

This works fine and dandy on the command line.  `git status` returns nothing.

In egit, I would expect the same as well.  However, if I open the commit dialog, I get a line that reads `Assume unchanged | <path_to_samples.xml>`.

Why would this happen?  If egit knows that it's assume unchanged, why does it still display in the commit dialog?  Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks,

Ken

Comment: Thanks @sehe.  This seems to occur only on files that are removed.  If I simply assume-unchange the samples.xml through the cmdline, egit properly registers it as unchanged as well.  It's only when I remove samples.xml do I see a discrepancy.  BTW, egit has a command line?

Comment: Never mind. I simply don't understand the question. What tool ways what when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `--assume-unchanged`. It is meant to say to git that I won't change this file, so don't bother looking at ( so that you can perform better on some less than efficient filesystems ) Now, you say that, but you go ahead and rm it?

With that said, since `git status` is respecting your delete, egit should do that as well, so probably you can raise this with egit developers and ask them if this was intentional.

Comment: Thanks!  --assume-unchanged makes much more sense now.  Would --skip-worktree be the better option to use instead?

Comment: @Ken Hirakawa Yeah I believe `--skip-worktree` can be an option ( just realized that you are one who asked the other question that I had answered ) but I see that TortoiseGit behaves pretty much to the expectation, so it is Egit guys who may need to look at how they handle this.

Comment: Yup, I got --skip-worktree from your other answer =).  I'll need to look into TortoiseGit (I've heard good and bad things about it).  I did file a defect for egit.  Hope they get to it soon.

Comment: btw, a bug related to this that I've submitted to egit has been resolved -> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347067